# How to delete files from master of stash

Tags: git-stash

Hi anybody could help me in deleting files from the master of stash?
I am new to stash and git commands and while commiting the initial version to stash all the files from the project folder got committed to the repository but i want that files to be placed inside  a folder wheras now it is all scattered over there. Please do help me in deleting those files and again commit the files inside the folder.Is this possible or do I need to delete the repsitory itself?

Answer (score 0):

A stash is a patch and is local.

You could save a stash to a file with `git stash show -p > stash1.patch` and remove it with `git stash drop` (apply and remove it with `git stash pop`), otherwise follow the [`git-stash` documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) and tutorial: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing; there is almost everything you need to know in the manual...